# Oracle: Change user of current connection

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

i have the situation that i am connecting to a Oracle Database as SYS User.
We have some 3rd Party applications installed which uses the USER-Variable.

Now i have some special situations where we want to execute code of the 3rd Party schemas from the SYS-User. The problem is, that the USER-Variable is "SYS" and not the schemaname of the 3rd Party schema. I can not change the code to use CURRENT_SCHEMA instead of the USER variable.

Is there a way in SQLPLUS/Oracle to change the current user inside a connected SYS-Session?

I know that i can change the current_schema by altering the session, but is there a similar way to change the USER-Variable?

Comment: No, you cannot change the user without reconnecting into a new session. Changing `CURRENT_SCHEMA` only changes the default schema prefix used when referencing objects; it does not change anything about the actual user of the session.

Comment: Don't do this. Never run application code under the SYS user. Create an account for that application and log into that account and run/install their code.

Comment: 100% agree on that topic regarding not running apllication logic under SYS user. As mentioned, my question is about 3rd party legacy application and in a perfect world, i would also do solve the issue in my described way.